# Подключение material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui, next.js

Злравствуйте! Пытаюсь установить material-ui в проект на Next.js, использую команду npm i @material-ui/core, но терминал выдает такой текст:

```
PS D:\frontend\nextjs-app> npm i material-ui/core
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/material-ui/core.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NikName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-09T15_35_51_907Z-debug.log
PS D:\frontend\nextjs-app>
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вот так попробуйте - `npm i @material-ui/core`

Comment: Здравствуйте! И так пробовал такая же ошибка:(

Comment: Попробуйте еще удалить `package-lock.json` далее обновить `npm`, потом уже установить пакет